# How can I verify my Gmail Oauth process when I'm not given a verification code?

Tags: php, google-api, gmail, google-oauth

I have setup the PHP Google Gmail library as per https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php and have run it, been successfully sent through to the Google consent screen and am redirected back to my webpage:

`https://example.com/?code=4/LONG_STRING&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly`

I have tried pasting into my command line script (the quickstart.php) various parts of the LONG_STRING But it isn't clear which code I'm meant to paste (Line 40 "Enter verification code") as I wasn't given any specific output??

Comment: The _full_ value of the `code` parameter from that URL that you are getting redirected back to.

Comment: Doh! The code began code=4/0AY0 and the / threw me! I now get insufficient permissions/privileges but that is a whole other story

Comment: Shall I delete this or do you want to post an answer and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the *full* value of the `code` parameter from the URL you got redirected back to.

In your example, this would be `4/LONG_STRING`.

> The code began code=4/0AY0 and the / threw me!

The slash should actually be URL-encoded, but if you look at this in the browser address bar, it depends on the browser (/settings), whether it will show it already decoded again there. But in a real implementation you don’t have to worry about that much, because the step they are asking you to perform manually here, will be automated anyway, so it will just be fetched via `$_GET['code']` and then passed to the `fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode`.